# Why is the theoretical formulation not explaining why the graph of the square of the velocity and angular displacement is nonlinear (experimentally)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics, solid-mechanics, experimental-physics

So I did a wind tunnel experiment where I put a rope restrained (1 degree of freedom, so it can wave in the direction of the wind) at one end so that it displaces according to the variation in wind speed. I have a NON-LINEAR graph when I plot the wind speed and the angular displacement and I'm trying to explain why that's happening.

Here's a schematic of the problem that I've made. As we know, wind load has a linear relationship with the square of wind speed and a nonlinear relationship with wind speed. The opposite applies here. Why please? How can we consider friction in the rotation point? And we are considering only pure horizontal wind. [image]

Plot of tangent of theta (Y-axis) against the square of the wind speed (X-axis) just according to the mechanical analysis.
[image]

below is the experimental setup. How can we analyze the effect of friction at the rotation point O?
[image]

Comment: CAn you share the plot of the angular displacement with the wind speed or square of wind speed?

Comment: Also can you clarify whether the "rope" is rigid or its able to oscillate?

Comment: @NMech I don't know how to reply with an image so I just edited the main post. please check it out.

Comment: It is rigid and able to oscillate in the direction of the horizontal wind. It maintains it's straight shape throughout the displacement process (it's not flexible).

Comment: @AJN by the intended design, I want the rope angle to vary according to the variation in wind speed. So angular displacement is not an error.

Comment: "a linear relationship with the square of wind speed."   I'm pretty sure wind load changes with the square of the wind velocity, not linearly with the square of the velocity, which would mean it varies with the square-root of wind velocity.

Comment: What's the Reynolds number?  This looks like the sort of thing you'd expect to see if the Reynolds number is so low that skin friction drag dominates over pressure drag.

Comment: @DanielHatton I don't have that information, but it's low speed. 30m/s tops

Comment: @TigerGuy the graph of wind load against wind velocity is non-linear.

Comment: @Peelo You have the wind velocity.  I suppose you know the diameter of the rope?  And it's straightforward to look up the kinematic viscosity of air.  Then you can work out the Reynolds number.

Comment: ... the point being that 'As we know, wind load has a linear relationship with the square of wind speed' is true only if the Reynolds number exceeds some critical threshold (from memory, I think that critical threshold is a couple of hundred thousand).

Comment: @Peelo, yes it's non-linear.  Regular wind load against buildings is a function of the square of the velocity.

Comment: @Peelo Wind pressure against the building is a probobla, P = 0.00256 x V^2. It is conservatively **assumed** to be linear for the convenience of calculation.

Comment: Why deleted everything?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see the angles that you have are greater than 45 degrees. More specifically, $atan(2.25)=66^o$.

(Although probably not the only reason), the $C_L$, $C_D$ will change significantly between 90 and 30 degrees angle of attack.

[image]

**figure: variation angle of attack (source [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Variation-of-C-D-and-C-L-with-the-AOA_fig3_4361000))**

Both these coefficient have an effect on the torsional moment that raises the rope, therefore, since they have a non linear behavior, the angle will also have a linear relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Of course these your points are valid, but I need specific convincing reasons that actually explain the phenomena. Thank you again

Comment: Thinking about it even more, I now suspect friction in the restrained end Any ideas on how I can theoretically add this please? I'll add a schematic of the experimental setup to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but to question your formulation.

[image]

As you can see, due to the flexibility of the rope, at any given time its deformation is undetermined, thus affecting the angle of rotation. There are too many variables, your assumption of linear behavior is not valid. You shall try a rigid steel rod instead of the flexible rope.

Comment: It's a "rigid rope". The rope isn't flexible. It can be modeled as a rigid steel rod but doesn't weigh that much.